# presenting a modal view controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have this same piece of code in two different parts of my app.
In one section it is executed perfectly, and in the other it is completely ignored. I've put in a breakpoint and watched the program go through each line of this code without loading the next xib/class it is supposed to.

Here is the code:

```
UIViewController *nextController = [[ClassNameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MatchingView" bundle:nil];

[nextController performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self];

[self presentModalViewController:nextController  animated:YES];
```

Any ideas why this might be getting ignored and not presenting my viewController?

Comment: What's the point of `performSelector:withObject:`? Why not `nextController.delegate = self`?

Comment: why do you call `[nextController performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self];` instead of `[nextViewController setDelegate:self]`?

Comment: nextController.delegate = self; says "Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'" and [nextController setDelegate:self]; says "UIViewController does not declare a method with selector 'setDelegate'"

Comment: what are you doing in setDelegate selector ?

Comment: [nextController performSelector:~selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self]; allows me to call methods within the nextController  to the delegate viewController. For example, in the .h of the view I am loading, there is a ~protocol GameDelegate
- (void)backToMenu:(id)sender;
~end so that in the .m I can call [delegate backToMenu:self]; and it will execute the backToMenu function in my original viewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this code in viewDidLoad and moving it to viewDidAppear made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ..

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nextController  animated:YES];
```